# Changing date format on iOS

Tags: ios, date, format

I have some dates in this format :

```
2012-06-26 12:00:00 +0000
```

and what i want to do is convert them in this format :

```
Jun 26, 2012 12:00:00 AM
```

Is there an easy way to do this on obj-c , or i must parse everything hardcore , and make my own function for this? If yes , any ideas how this would look like , cause i am new on iOS.
Thank you very much for reading my post :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convert from 1 string to the other use the following

```
NSString *inputString = @"2012-06-26 12:00:00 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z"];//input

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:inputString];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSString *outputString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"output : %@",outputString);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should convert your string (with a NSDateFormatter ) in a NSDate and than convert it back to a NSString (still with the same NSDateFormatter) with the target format.

Here is an example of a NSDateFormatter :

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-04-01T22:00:00Z";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
NSDate *theDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```